# Adding and displaying input via Database in Managed Bean

Tags: java, database, jsf, xhtml, managed-bean

I am trying to add the input from my input text on `Index.xhtml` page to my database once added I want to add the display it on another page EG IndexOutput which I have made already

The problem I am having is that it does not display the input I enter

Only the input that is already pre-populated in the database gets displayed below I have all my (Java / XHTML / managed bean classes).

Index.xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
    <title>Product Table</title>

    <f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{productController.loadProducts()}" type="preRenderView" />       
    </f:metadata>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
    <h:form>
    ProdID: <h:inputText value="#{product.prodid}" 
            id="id" 
            p:placeholder="enter product id" 
            required="true"  
            requiredMessage="ID is mandatory" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Prod Desc: <h:inputText value="#{product.proddesc}" 
            p:placeholder="enter product name" 
            required="true"  
            requiredMessage="Name is mandatory" />
    <br />
    <br />


    <h:commandButton value="Display" action="IndexOutput" />

    </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

IndexOutput.xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
    <title>Product Table Output</title>

    <f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{productController.loadProducts()}"      type="preRenderView" />
    </f:metadata>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
    <h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Add" action="Index" />
    <br />
    <br />
       <h:dataTable 
         value="#{productController.products}" 
         var="p" 
         headerClass="table-header" 
         rowClasses="table-odd-row,table-even-row">
    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Product</f:facet>
        #{p.prodid}
        #{p.proddesc}
    </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

ProductController.java

```
    package lab10;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    //import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;

    @ManagedBean
    public class ProductController {
      private ArrayList<Product> products;
      private DAO dao;

      public ProductController() {
      try {
            dao = new DAO();
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getProducts() {
      return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(ArrayList<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public void loadProducts() throws Exception {
         products = dao.getProductDetails();
    } 
    }
```

Product.java

```
            package lab10;

    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

    @ManagedBean

    public class Product {

        private int prodid;
        private String proddesc;

        public Product() {
        }

        public Product(int prodid, String proddesc) {
            super();
            this.prodid = prodid;
            this.proddesc = proddesc;
        }

        public int getProdid() {
            return prodid;
        }

        public void setProdid(int prodid) {
            this.prodid = prodid;
        }

        public String getProddesc() {
            return proddesc;
        }

        public void setProddesc(String proddesc) {
            this.proddesc = proddesc;
        }

    }
```

DAO.java

```
            package lab10;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.naming.*;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    public class DAO {

        private DataSource mysqlDS;

        public DAO() throws Exception {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            String jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/employeesdb14";
            mysqlDS = (DataSource) context.lookup(jndiName);
        }
        /*************************************************************************************/
        public ArrayList<Product> getProductDetails() throws Exception {
            ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
            Connection conn = mysqlDS.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement myStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from product;");
            ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery();
        /*************************************************************************************/     
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("PRODID");
                String pname = rs.getString("DESCRIP");
                products.add(new Product(id, pname));
            }

            return products;
        }


    }
```

Comment: By `Index.xhmtl`, did you mean `Index.html`?

Comment: hi ..nope im using xhtml pages

Comment: Right, so `Index.xhtml`, not `Index.xhmtl`? That seems like an error, would you correct it?

Comment: The pages work fine. They are both XHTML pages and the data is displayed from what is already in the Database. it is just trying to add data to the database and display it is the main problem